# Why is nginx serving static files out of the wrong directory?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get nginx to serve a static file from the root url eg. `http://localhost/favicon.ico`. My static assets are located in `/home/myuser/myapp/static/` and I have a `root /home/myuser/myapp/static/;` directive in my `server` section.

**Visiting `/favicon.ico` in my browser returns nothing, but the file is served correctly when visiting `/static/favicon.ico`.**

This means that nginx is treating `/home/myuser/myapp/` as the root instead of `/home/myuser/myapp/static/`, right? Shouldn't a request to `/favicon.ico` be served out of the static directory?

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  use epoll;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  upstream app_server {
    server unix:/sockets/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name 10.204.2.169 perf-test.debesys.net;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /home/myuser/myapp/static;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @app{
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the structure of `/home/myuser/myapp`:

```
├── constants.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── setup.sh
├── static
│   └── favicon.ico
├── tasks.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the root into the location section.

```
  server {
    listen 80 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name 10.204.2.169 perf-test.debesys.net;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @app;
      root /home/myuser/myapp/static;
    }
```

Comment: Its never a good idea to place root inside of a location block. While it will work, its redundant.